# ext.net how can i use more than data_index on a same Column

Tags: extjs, ext.net

i have the following :

```
<ext:RecordField Name="ID" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="UserName" />
                    <ext:RecordField Name="FirstName" />
                     <ext:RecordField Name="LasttName" />
            i want use  FirstName& LasttName on : 

 <ext:Column ColumnID="Name" Sortable="false" DataIndex="????"
     Resizable="false" MenuDisabled="true"/>
```

**What i need is to use more than data_index on a same Column** is that possible, how can i achieve that? thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about ext.net but I think you are looking for a renderer functionality. You create your own column where you concat the values from other columns like: `FirstName+LastName`

Comment: Yeah in native ExtJS it's the renderer function as A1rPun has stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//In your head:

<script type="text/javascript">
var myRenderer = function(value, metadata, record) {
    return record.get('FirstName') + ' ' + record.get('LastName');
}
</script>


<ext:Column ColumnID="Name" Sortable="false" Resizable="false" MenuDisabled="true">
    <Renderer Fn="myRenderer" />
</ext:Column>
```

Comment: You can also set the `.Handler` property, which avoids having to create a separate named function when you're just doing a simple manipulation. **Example** `<Renderer Handler="return record.get('FirstName') + ' ' + record.get('LastName');" />`

Comment: Ah ok, as I sayd, I'm not familier with Ext.net.