# Ext.Net 3.2 - Fully color gridpanel cell

Tags: extjs, extjs3, ext.net, gridpanel

I would fully color a grid panel cell with Ext.Net 3.2 framework; I have tried with render:

```
<ext:Column ID="ColumnSTATO_VEICOLO" runat="server" Width="105" Text="Stato veicolo" DataIndex="STATO_VEICOLO">
    <Renderer Handler="return Ext.String.format('<span style=background-color:green; height:100%; padding:0px; width:100%;>{0}</span>', record.data.STATO_VEICOLO)" />
```

But I get only this result:[image]

where the cells are only partially colored.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Ext.net, but what you are doing would be as follows in plain ExtJS:

```
renderer:function(value, metaData, record) {
  return Ext.String.format('<span style=background-color:green; height:100%; padding:0px; width:100%;>{0}</span>', record.data.STATO_VEICOLO);
}
```

and what you really want to do, in plain ExtJS, is as follows:

```
renderer:function(value,metaData) {
  metaData.style="background-color:green";
  return value;
}
```

You would "just" have to turn that into Ext.net code.

Comment: Btw. I found how to do it in Ext.Net [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413845/ext-net-how-can-i-use-more-than-data-index-on-a-same-column).

Comment: I have tried this: `<Renderer Handler="return Ext.String.format('<metaData style=background-color:green;>{0}</metaData>', record.data.STATO_VEICOLO)" />`    but the result is the same

Comment: I try this  `<Renderer Handler="return Ext.String.format('<div style=background-color:green; height:100%; padding:0px; width:100%;>{0}</div>', record.data.STATO_VEICOLO)" />` and it's almost perfect...but remain a little white padding space...!!

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Please read [the accepted answer behind the link I provided in the first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413845/ext-net-how-can-i-use-more-than-data-index-on-a-same-column) to see how to make a renderer that accepts two parameters; and then use my second snippet inside that renderer.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander ! I found the solution using your suggestions. I share it to help who had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution and I want share it with the community:

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ChangevLivUrgenzaColorMetaData = function (value, metaData) {

        var color = '#66ff66';

        if (value.indexOf('0') > -1) {
            color = '#d9d9d9';  //grey  
        }
        else if (value.indexOf('1') > -1) {
            color = '#66ff66';  //green 
        }
        else if (value.indexOf('2') > -1) {
            color = '#ffff80';   //yellow  
        }
        else if (value.indexOf('3') > -1) {
            color = '#ff9900';  //orange  
        }
        else if (value.indexOf('4') > -1) {
            color = '#ff4d4d';  //red 
        }

        metaData.style = "background-color:" + color;
        return value;
    }
```

**Asp.Net**

```
<ext:Column ID="ColumnLIV_URGENZA" runat="server" Text="Livello urgenza" DataIndex="LIV_URGENZA" Width="150">
    <Renderer Fn="ChangevLivUrgenzaColorMetaData" />                                        
</ext:Column>
```

The trick is to use:

```
metaData.style
```

The result is:

[image]